# How do i block all VPN connections to my server?

Tags: java, linux, server

I have a server in one game (it's called Mindustry).
On average, 60 people constantly play on the server, about 10,000 unique users enter per day.
Some people who use VPNs bypass all the bans and interfere with regular players. I need an easy and free way to block all VPN connections to my server.

Some info:

- the server is running on a dedicated host with Ubuntu 20.04
- i have a root access on the host
- this game (Mindustry) supports loading java mods & plugins, they can track the connection of a player and get his ip-address
- the game code is here: https://github.com/anuken/mindustry

I tried using public free anti-vpn APIs, but i need at least 10000 queries per day, however no API gives you that much.
I also tried to set up the firewall on my host, but idk where can i find all VPN IPs and how do i block them all.

*Sorry for my bad english, it's not my national language*
*Also it's my first time asking something on StackOverflow*

Comment: This might be better asked on Super User.  https://superuser.com/questions

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow.  Along the lines of cliff's comment, you might consider looking at server fault as well.  https://serverfault.com/